# My deployed app works fine on desktop but is a blank screen on mobile phones

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku, deployment, mern

I deployed my react app to heroku and the app is working fine on my desktop (chrome, linux) but when I go on my Safari or Chrome app on my iPhone the screen is rendered blank across all pages. My app is here [app](https://mood-verse.herokuapp.com/)

You can take a look and see on your phone but any help would be much appreciated as I don't even know how to target this problem!

My repo is here https://github.com/junaama/Mood-Verse

Comment: Without any code its hard to say, but I once had this problem because I was using Redux-dev-tools in the app, so it worked on the browser where I had redux-dev-tools installed and came up blank all on the others. Are you using any browser extensions?

Comment: Hi @junaama, I have also deployed my mern app on heroku. it works fine on desktop chrome but on mobile chrome its loading forever. I have tried your app on android chrome it is working. can you write an answer to your question? how are you able to render on the chrome mobile?